# C# unable to read json from file and loop through it

Tags: c#, json, .net, entity-framework

So, I have JSON data from my file which is currently getting from the server.

This is part of the format of my file

```
[{"Table":"Starters","Label":"Starters","Columns":[{"Field":"Desc","Display":"Description",{"Field":"Name","Display":"Starter Name",},
{"Table":"Main","Label":"Main Course","Columns":[{"Field":"Desc","Display:"Description",{"Field":"Name","Display":"Main Course Name",}
```

And for the code

```cs
 public static void getTables() {

     var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(String.Format("{0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"]));

     using(StreamReader file =
         File.OpenText(path))
     using(JsonTextReader reader =
         new JsonTextTeader(file)) {
         JValue obj =
             (JValue) JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
     }
 }
```

This is part of the code. There are many tables and I want only the table name and label which I will append to a list or dictionary. Can you help, please? And I don't have a predefined class for table and label

Comment: Your file is not actually valid JSON.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker, its only part of the JSON file. But this format is repeated for the other tables. When I pass it through a foreach loop, i get conversion errros. Can you help? :/

Comment: @DanielEarwicker, still cannot proceed :(

Answer (score 0):

Even from the partial JSON you've provided, it is clear that it is not valid JSON. This can be seen more easily if you insert some line breaks and indent to show the hierarchy:

```
[
    {
        "Table":"Starters",
        "Label":"Starters",
        "Columns":
        [
            {
                "Field":"Desc",
                "Display":"Description",
                {"Field":"Name","Display":"Starter Name",},
```

In JSON there are two structural types:

- arrays, in `[square brackets]`, which contain zero or more values separated by commas
- objects, in `{curly braces}`, which also contain values separate by commas, but each value must be preceded by a property name and a colon.

So there is a problem with the last line above, which doesn't have a property name. It should be something like:

```
"Field":"Desc",
"Display":"Description",
"SomeProperty": {"Field":"Name","Display":"Starter Name"}
```

Note: I've also removed the unnecessary comma after `"Starter Name"` which is also not valid in JSON.

Comment: so if it was a valid one, how would I have looped through it to get the table and label?

Comment: any idea how can I do it pls?